# Spring @Transactional method Error handling

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I am using a Transactional method using `@Transactional` annotation. I am trying to save an object to the database using JpaRepository's save() method. (which will throw an error due to constraints on database relation.)

Now, when I debugged the program, I found out that an exception is thrown at the end of transactional method not when `save` method is called. This is quite different behaviour from that of a non-transactional method.

Can someone explain why is that so? Why is exception thrown at the end of transactional method and not when actually it should occur.

My second question is, when the method is Transactional, exception thrown is `DataViolationException` and when it is non-transactional, exception thrown is `PSQLException`(using Postgres database). Why is that so?

Below is the code

```
@Transactional
public ResponseType methodA(UserObject userObject) {
    //save call
    jpaRepoObject.save(userObject);
    //next call will fail due to relational constraints on database
    jpaRepoObject.save(userObject); //should throw PSQLException/DataViolationException

     return new ResponseType("success"); //Error thrown after this line.
}
```

Comment: Because the save is only performed at the end of the transaction

Comment: Could you please post your code, so we can fix it?

Comment: More relevantly, tell us *what exception* and the message (not necessarily the stack trace in this case).

Comment: @NielsNet What if a transaction contains more than one save calls. They both will be done at the end of the transaction as well ? What if the the next save is dependent on the previous save and some other code ?

Comment: @JBDouble05 Updated the post with code!

Comment: @chrylis DataViolationException or PSQLException. Basically exceptions thrown at when the constraint on a table in my relational database(Postgres) is violated during a write operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of JPA called transactional write-behind. All the inserts and updates your code is executing get stored by the Jpa implementation until the transaction is flushed. This lets the jpa implementation reorder these actions to take place in whatever order makes the most sense.

Flushing means executing all the actions that have been stored up so far by the entityManager instance. You can tell the entityManager to flush or it will automatically flush once the transaction boundary is reached.

An example of when you would flush explicitly would be if you are inserting an entity and you need it to have an ID generated for it so you can use it later in the same method.

You can always run sql within a transaction and commit or rollback later. Flushing runs the sql but doesn’t commit.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Nathan. Just wanted to clarify this! So, in case of a transactional method commit or rollback will be done at the end of transactional method irrespective of either I use save() or saveAndFlush(). Right?

Comment: Also, can you please answer my second question as well. I am getting 2 different exceptions on same operation in case of transactional and non transactional methods. Would be of great help! Thanks!

Comment: Rishabh: transaction will commit or rollback regardless. When you remove the @Transactional annotation each statement executes in its own transaction.

Answer (score 0):

`save` doesn't immediately flush data to underlying database. First, entities are saved into first level cache, and, when time to flush come(at the end of transaction - like in your case, or when a query is issued), only then entities are saved into database.

To see behaviour which you expect, use `saveAndFlush` method.

Comment: But when I remove the @Transactional annotation from my method, then the error is thrown from the save call itself! Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: Also, If I will use saveAndFlush(), will the whole transactional method still be able to rollback in case of an error?